# Find a substring in parts within a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python, and came across a situation where I have to find a substring within a string but in parts.

For example, my string could be
My string="this is stack overflow" OR
My string="this stack is overflow"

And i have to find if stack overflow is present.

The order must be same, but there can be anything written in between two portions that is stack and overflow.

Any help is appreciated.!

Comment: your string to find will always be of two words? like `stack overflow` or `some string`

Comment: Do you need to find if every letter of the first string is available in the second? Can you provide some sample input and expected output? It's hard to understand without a specific example

Comment: What did you code? Where is your [mre]? What is wrong with it? You could try to split your search term into single words (google python split()) and check if all() words are in the text you are looking through. If you also need positional awareness (stack before overflow, not after) you can play around with enumerate() of your splitted word texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this several ways. The two I can think of are:

1. [Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
2. Finding two strings in the same string.

```py
s1 = "this is stack overflow"
s2 = "this stack is overflow"
```

Using regular expressions you can do it this way:

```py
re_so = re.compile('stack(.*)overflow') #Here's the regex to use...
if m := re_so.search(s1):
    print('We have a match')
else:
    print('No match...')
if m := re_so.search(s2):
    print('We have a match')
else:
    print('No match...')
```

Using finding string in the same string:

```py
if ('stack' in s1) and ('overflow' in s1):
    print('We have a match')
else:
    print('No match...')
if ('stack' in s2) and ('overflow' in s2):
    print('We have a match')
else:
    print('No match...')
```

In all cases your output should be

```
We have a match
```

Comment: Thank you. But i was looking for something with a single if condition. Can I create a regex which will check for "stack" and "overflow" by ignoring anything in between them?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that piece of code in there. I've done that now. The regex is  `re_so = re.compile('stack(.*)overflow')`. The part `(.*)` means to match every character 0 or more times (the `.` means every character, the `*` means 0 to many times greedy, the brackets are for grouping). To learn more about regex: [look here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 2):

use regular expression, code below

```
import re

mystr = ["this is stack overflow", "this stack is overflow"]
my_key = "stack overflow"


rexpr = re.compile(".*".join(my_key.split()))
for s in mystr:
    print(re.search(rexpr, s))
```

**output**

```
<re.Match object; span=(8, 22), match='stack overflow'>
<re.Match object; span=(5, 22), match='stack is overflow'>
```

Comment: good approach, you need to ensure that the words in `my_key` don't contain regex specific characters (use `re.escape` if needed)

Answer (score 0):

```
s="This stack is overflow"
a=["stack","overflow"]

def f(s,a):
    s=s.split(" ")
    n,m=len(s),len(a)
    i=j=0
    while i<n:
        if s[i]==a[j]:
            j+=1
            if j==m:
                return True
        i+=1
    return False
print(f(s,a))
```